# Nancy test fails because of missing modulePath for FakeNancyModule

Tags: c#, testing, nancy

I get the following when I try to test a Nancy module:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  205 Missing requested Instance property
>   "modulePath" for InstanceKey "Nancy.Testing.Fakes.FakeNancyModule"

Here's my test:

```
public class when_a_user_logs_in_successfully
{
    static Browser _browser;
    static BrowserResponse _response;

     Establish context = () =>
         {
            var bootstrapper = new BlurtsBootsrapper();
            _browser = new Browser(bootstrapper); //throws exception here
        };

     Because of = () => _response = _browser.Get("/Login", with => with.HttpRequest());

     It should_return_a_successful_response = () => _response.Body.ShouldNotBeNull();
}
```

Here's my BlurtsBootstrapper:

```
public class BlurtsBootsrapper : StructureMapNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(StructureMap.IContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

        container.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<BlurtsRegistry>());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the stack trace? Also, do you do any more registrations in _BlurtsRegistry_ ? Thanks

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on my end. It appears it's trying to create an instance of _FakeNancyModule_ using it's most greedy constructor and since it's of type _string_ there is no value for it to resolve in the container. Will look into a fix on our end

Comment: Is there anything I can do as a work-around for now?

Comment: I tried giving the module a modulePath in the base ctor, but that didn't work.

Comment: You can use the configurable bootstrapper as a workaround for now. It's TinyIoC based, but it will let you test your routes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449760/119562) that led me to the answer that worked for me

In your bootstrapper, add the following:

```
container.Configure(x => {
    x.SelectConstructor(()=>new FakeNancyModule());
    x.AddRegistry<BlurtsRegistry>();
})
```

At least this should work until the `StructureMapBootstrapper` itself is updated.

Comment: This worked for me. Created a new NancyBootsrapper inheriting from the bootstrapper in the project and added teh x.SelectConstructor.

Answer (score 0):

In 0.10 you must do this by overriding `ConfigureRequestContainer(IContainer container, NancyContext context)`

It looks like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(IContainer container, NancyContext context)
{
    container.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.SelectConstructor(() => new FakeNancyModule());
    });
    base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
}
```

They said they will try and fix it for 0.11

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.StructureMap/issues/8