# What's the difference between these two StructureMap configs?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dependency-injection, structuremap

We're struggling with understanding the difference between these two ways to configure StructureMap. Our understanding is that they should be identical but we get different results between these two lines inside of Initialize:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IBusinessRelationsContext>().Use<BusinessRelationsContext>().Ctor<string>().Is(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessRelationsContext"].ConnectionString);
    x.For<IBusinessRelationsContext>().Use(_ => new BusinessRelationsContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessRelationsContext"].ConnectionString));
});
```

(we only use 1 of the two at a time - not both, obviously)

Our various constructor signatures on this object (it's EF4 stuff if you care):

```
public BusinessRelationsContext();
public BusinessRelationsContext(string connectionString);
public BusinessRelationsContext(EntityConnection connection);
```

The code we use to invoke this is:

```
ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<IBusinessRelationsContext>();
```

The difference in behavior that we see is that the line that includes `Ctor<string>` fails because StructureMap fails with a 202 "No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Data.Common.DbConnection" (we have no idea why it thinks it needs this). However, if I comment that line out and use the other one, it works perfectly as we would expect. Given that the other one works, I suspect that my understanding that it shouldn't need config for DbConnection is correct.

So rather than tracking down WHY it needs the DbConnection I would rather track down the answer to my question: What's the difference between these two?

Comment: This is somewhat important because we have always used the `.Ctor` way of doing this in the past (and it has always worked) but given that it started failing (we're not sure why), we need to understand this better. We're missing something conceptually here and I don't want to have a ticking timebomb...

Comment: I think I've actually seen this myself too, where using Ctor just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding the `Ctor` way of doing it essentially mine says, "For *IBusinessRelationsContext* instances, use the *BusinessRelationsContext* object and call the *Constructor* with a *single string* parameter and pass in what `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessRelationsContext"].ConnectionString` evaluates to as that string parameter"? Is there anything else to it?

Comment: The funny thing is, we use the `Ctor` way with other Context objects ALL over the place! Because our DB is so large, we have ~20 different contexts as we chop it into sections and it works for all 20 of them. It just so happens that in these particular unit tests that this one particular context is failing yet other contexts work fine with the `Ctor` method. (All contexts are code-gen'd from the same template, so there's NO difference there!)

Comment: That's definitely my understanding of it and I've used SM for 3+ years. The last time I wanted to do something like this I'm pretty sure I ended up having to do similar to what you did with manually newing the object in the Use.

Comment: We're fairly new(ish) to it - only been using it ~1.5 years with nobody really experienced at it (we were all equally noob 1.5 yrs ago and learned together). So I'm definitely open to my ignorance and somebody pointing out a fundamental flaw in my understanding. Also open to it simply being a bug but I'd be kinda surprised...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think StructureMap is selecting the most complex constructor to try to create your datacontext. What you have defined up there with the Ctor call is a definition on how to define that class using a less complex constructor.

So your definition isn't incorrect, it's just that StructureMap isn't calling the constructor you think it's supposed to be calling.

**Note: I usually use your second call, since I know what constructor will be called, even if you have to add new ones for testing or other purposes.**

```
x.For<IBusinessRelationsContext>().Use(_ => new BusinessRelationsContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessRelationsContext"].ConnectionString));
```

Comment: This is it but there's more to it than that. I'm about to post the solution to make the .Ctor way to work! :-D

Comment: Awarded you the answer to the question but I posted the solution to the problem in another answer. :)

Comment: Awesome that you figured it out. You don't have to give me the credit if yours is the correct one. I want people to see the correct answer. Even if it means my cred is lower.

Comment: Well, your answer WAS the correct answer to the question. The question was, "What's the difference?" and your correct answer, that I wasn't previously considering, was that "StructureMap isn't calling the constructor I think it's supposed to be calling". My answer that I posted was the answer to the obvious follow-up question: "How do I make it call the constructor I think it's supposed to be calling?" :)

Answer (score 0):

So I had somebody offline help me with this (didn't think I'd have any offline resources on this!) and the problem is as Khalid Abuhakmeh explained - it's picking the most complex one (the "greediest" - [read more here](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm)).

Now that we know the problem, we can look for the solution. In my case (and the case of those commenting here), the solution is to add a line like so:

```
x.SelectConstructor<IBusinessRelationsContext>(() => new BusinessRelationsContext(""));
```

Comment: IMHO, this is absolutely terrible that StructureMap arbitrarily picks a constructor even when my config line explicity specifies, in a strongly-typed and uniquely-identifying way, the arguments for the constructor. That's bad! (coming from somebody who has never developed a DI engine before)

Comment: It is not arbitrary. StructureMap always picks the greediest constructor. It is well-documented behavior. Your config line (in the question) specifies the value for one constructor parameter - it does not specify the constructor. It is possible to specify the string constructor param, while letting the the container resolve any other params automatically.

Comment: @Joshua: In this scenario, I have two equally-greedy constructors. Two constructors take a single parameter. One of them happens to take in a single string (and I specify a string type) while the other takes in a single EntityConnection. We have been using the `.Ctor` method successfully for a year and a half but with this problem we began hitting, for the first time, the problem where StructureMap would choose the other constructor instead. Both constructors have been available for 1.5 years and signatures have not changed. Explain the sudden behavior change if you don't think it's arbitrary.

Comment: The fact that the greediest is selected is not arbitrary - it appeared that is what you were objecting to. If you have a tie for the greediest, then yes, it will be somewhat arbitrary, in that it relies on the order the constructors are returned from .NET reflection. It always selects the first one. If the .NET runtime changes, or its algorithm returns them in a different order (which is certainly possible - the reflection API does not guarantee order), you will get a different constructor selected. Either you upgraded your FX, or you've just always got the expected ctor by dumb luck, til now.